# Img not rendering on page

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to load an image of a chicken onto my web page but it's not rendering at all. Here is my code pen: https://codepen.io/beckytownsend/pen/EvVjwa

I can't think where I am going wrong! If you go into the codepen (or snippet) and open up as a full view you will see my cow image in there.

```css
.body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/40000/velka/the-house-in-the-field.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -150px;
}

img {
  width: 25%;
}

#cow {
  margin: 700px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Cow_cartoon_04.svg/1280px-Cow_cartoon_04.svg.png" id="cow">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Rooster_cartoon_04.svg/2000px-Rooster_cartoon_04.svg.png" id="chicken">

</body>
```

Comment: Why do you have `margin: 700px;`?

Answer (score 0):

The 700px margin you are setting on the cow is pushing the chicken off the page. Remove it and they will both move to the top left corner next to each other.

I'm assuming you are trying to position them in specific spots based on the background. This isn't a responsive solution if you resize the browser but should get you started.

```
#cow,
#chicken {
   position: absolute;
}

#cow {
   bottom: 60px;
   right: 130px;
}

#chicken {
   bottom: 20px;
   right: 600px;
   max-width: 140px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Chicken is there, just very low, and you can't see it because your container div is too large... You need to position it properly. Try adding this to your css:

```
#chicken {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
```

EDIT: Or.... remove the margin:700px;

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try margin-top instead of margin. Using just "margin" will create a 700px margin on all sides of the cow, pushing the chicken image out of frame.

```css
#cow{
    margin-top:700px:
 }
```